# Does uninstalling and installing a MacOS App Store App do anything?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I have some issue with a Mac OS application that I got from the App Store. The support suggested to uninstall the app and install it again.  My question is: Is there any way this can help?

There is a separation of programs and user data in MacOS, so uninstalling the program and reinstalling it should be no-op in total. Is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be. It won't delete any of your documents, but you might want to back up these locations, if they exist:

- ~/Library/Preferences/*com*.*whatever*.*appname*.plist
- ~/Library/Application Support/*AppName*

You almost certainly **don't need to do this**--I don't know what exactly the App Store uninstall process does--but it doesn't hurt to be safe.

**Update**: Due to [sandboxing](https://developer.apple.com/app-sandboxing/), you won't find anything in either of these locations. (All apps from the App Store are sandboxed, but apps you get somewhere else probably aren't.) You should look here instead:

- ~/Library/Containers/*com*.*whatever*.*appname*

Comment: You're right, Mac App Store apps are sandboxed so you won't find anything in either of those locations

Comment: and uninstalling won't touch anything under ~/Library/Containers/... right?

Comment: It probably won't, but I don't know for sure. That's why I suggested backing it up, just in case. Of course, if you haven't changed anything to do with the app since your last Time Machine backup, you're already covered.

Comment: I've tried it. No changes to that location during uninstall.